# Django, What is the best practice to add a column to a table when 99% of the column is default value?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I'd like to add a column to a table like

```
class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    birthday = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

and now I want to add

```
is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

but there are only 3 administrators so 99% of the column value is False

I think just for 3 rows adding a column is a waste of resources.

Is there another best way to handle this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Auth and Admin apps that come with Django, you'll break everything if you don't have the columns those apps use to indicate user and administrator status: "is_active", "is_staff", and "is_superuser"..  Even if you use Django Auth's Custom User Model capability, your custom User model still needs to have those boolean fields.  So if you are using those apps you might as well use the fields they provide.

Now, if your "is_admin" flag has absolutely no meaning to Django Admin or Django Auth, but only means something to your own application code, then you can do it as a simple boolean column, or you can do it as a foreign key relationship.. eg. you can create an `Administrators` model which contains a ForeignKey field back to User.  Any User in the Administrators table is an administrator.  So you won't have that field cluttering up your User table.  The downside is that you'll have to do a join every time you want to know whether the user is an administrator or not...  If you plan to have millions of users on your site, it's probably worth it, if you have a few hundred or even a few thousand, maybe not...

Comment: So as long as is_admin doesn't belong to any installed app or plugins in Django, I have 2 options which are just adding an 'is_admin' field to User model or creating an Administrator model related to User model by adding a foreign key. And if the number of users is huge, second options is the best practice. Am I getting right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.  But you have to think about for example are you going to be checking administrator status often.  If you are constantly joining to that related table to find out if the user has a row there, you aren't saving anything.  It's an age-old database problem.. balancing between best design and best performance.   But what I am saying as well is that if you are already using the Django Admin app, and your "is_admin" are the same people who have access to django Admin, then you can just use the already existing ;'is_staff' field that controls access to Admin.

Comment: Thanks! I don't use /admin URL but I made another URL for admin page so is_admin means nothing to the new admin page.